# Troubleshooting jQuery not loading in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I built [this site](http://www.streetofwalls.com) and I've tested it on every browser I can get my hands on from IE8 and up. Everything works normally on my version of IE8 and any version I've been able to test.

The problem: My site isn't working properly in my client's version of IE8. The error messages they reported indicate that jQuery is not getting loaded, which (not surprisingly) is breaking scripts left and right. They assure me that there is no firewall preventing jquery from getting loaded from an external site. I also had them confirm that Active Scripting is enabled under Internet Options. I'm running out of ideas for why *their* IE8 isn't working but mine is.

They're on Windows XP. Here's the full version number of their IE8 I was given: v8.06001.18702c0 128bit

Does anyone know of what might be happening? Do I need to somehow try to track down that EXACT version?

The client showed me this screenshot of an error message. I checked each line referenced and it's basically throwing erros as soon as jQuery is referenced in those scripts.
[image]

Comment: As part of troubleshooting this, have you tried loading the script from your local domain?

Comment: What isn't working?  I'm using the same exact browser you mentioned and don't seem to be having any issues

Comment: I'm adding the screenshot they gave me to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand this solution, but the problem was resolved when the client opened the developer tools (Tools > Developer Tools ) and toggled from "IE8 Compatibility View Mode" to IE8 Mode. For me (and everyone else I know) this is already the default setting. The client works in an office with lots of firewalls and security settings on all their software, so I assume their browsers are set that way for some security-related reason.

I did a quick look and found this reasonably instructive page about compatibility mode:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/23/understanding-compatibility-modes-in-internet-explorer-8.aspx

Answer (score 2):

As a quick fix, always use a fallback when calling a remote script just in case that remote server is unavailable:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"><\/script>')</script>
```

This way, a local version is loaded if the remote is not found. Not sure this will fix your issue, but it's worth a shot. Also, make sure that jQuery is actually loaded before you call any methods on it using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
...your script
}
```

Comment: [HTML5Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) does this standard. Seems like overkill, but it just might fix this case.

Comment: I'm already loading scripts inside the document ready() function, but I'll try the fallback you listed and report back. It's a little tricky because I'm loading scripts through Wordpress, which handles the queuing and dependancies, etc.

Comment: In your main.js, line 103 you have: jQuery(function($)... - that needs to be in the document ready method.

Comment: @DeweyOx Thanks! I'll look into that. It turned their browser was in a weird mode (see my answer below), but all your suggestions are great.